# Loading from network, showing on UI, and save to disk with RxJava

Tags: android, database, multithreading, rx-java, rx-android

I'm now working on a task that will fetch data from the network, showing on the UI, and save the data to local database to use later. Currently I'm doing as following:

```
//Cloud loading
Observable<MyModel> loadDataFromCloud();

//Database
Observable<MyModel> saveDataToDisk(MyModel myModel);

//Load data
loadDataFromCloud()
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .flatMap(new Func1<MyModel, Observable<MyModel>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<MyModel> call(MyModel myModel) {
      return saveDataToDisk(myModel);
    }
  })
  .subscribe(new Subscriber<MyModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
      //exception handling
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(MyModel myModel) {
      //bind myModel to UI
    }
  });
```

This approach works fine, but since the data model gets more complex, and the database get bigger, it's not efficient anymore, because all the database transactions are now executed on main thread AND the UI need to wait until that transactions are done to have the data.

I'm now changing to this new approach:

```
//A Singleton
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());

//Load data
loadDataFromCloud()
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .flatMap(new Func1<MyModel, Observable<MyModel>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<MyModel> call(MyModel myModel) {
      try {
        //bind myModel to UI
        return Observable.just(s);
      } catch(Exception e) {
        return Observable.error(e)
      }
    }
  })
  .observeOn(scheduler)
  .flatMap(new Func1<MyModel, Observable<MyModel>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<MyModel> call(MyModel myModel) {
      return saveDataToDisk(myModel);
    }
  })
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(new Subscriber<MyModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
      //exception handling
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(MyModel myModel) {
      //do nothing
    }
  });
```

I'm using `Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())` to ensure all the database transactions will be thread-safe.

And I have some questions:

1. Does using`Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())` to ensure all the database transactions will be thread-safe is the right way?
2. Is there better way to achieve this goal, since the last `onNext()` just doing nothing seems to be unwise
3. With RxJava can we start doing two task as the same time on two different thread (showing on the UI and saving to disk)

I've searched for awhile and got some articles like [this one](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/) but they doesnt go directly to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,  way in the first place are you doing IO operation on the main thread,  it's a bad practice and in android it can lead to anr.

1. Basically it should sync,  but as long as your using the same `Scheduler` across your app,  otherwise you will create new thread for each subscribe to this observable. But, some a bit odd to do that,  as DB operations are thread safe usually.
2. In your scenario, you want to show the ui and you can `saveDataToDisk()` in parallel without waiting for it, so you can use `doOnNext` operator to initiate the saving operation on a different observable (you don't care about its results) without observing it's result.

So to sum up you should something like:

```
loadDataFromCloud()
   .doOnNext(data - > saveDataToDisk().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe(data -> //uodate your ui)
```

Dan Lew post is a great example,  you should follow the examples there.

Comment: thank you @yosriz, the `.doOnNext(data - > saveDataToDisk().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))` totally did the trick